# Single group function - product count by category and region

Tags: sql, group-by

I looked online and could not find answer to the following problem.

I would like to create the table below. I could create all columns except `Count_product_A` and `count_product_B`.

link to table:

[image: Link to table]

link to table1:

[image: Linke to table 1]

```
Select 
  Region_flag, type, count(total product)
  ,sum(Case when product in ('A') then count(total product) END) as count_product_A
  ,sum(Case when product in ('B') then count(total product) END) as count_product_B
FROM Table1 
Group by
  Region_flag, type
```

Comment: what do you want count_product_A and _B to be? The SUM of a COUNT? Or just the Count of the product?

Comment: Yes the sum of a count

Comment: can you add a portion of your table?

Comment: sure, here is the link:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhx3A.png

Comment: i meant your Table1, not the result table :D

Comment: sure here is Table1 link. In the code above, I built a case where when quantity is below 100 then it is "type 1" else "type2" but did not include it here for simplicity. https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKWPW.png

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 2):

Try this query:

```
SELECT 
  region_flag, type,
  count(1) AS count_total,
  sum(CASE WHEN product IN ('A') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_product_A,
  sum(CASE WHEN product IN ('B') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_product_B
FROM
  table1 
GROUP BY
  region_flag, type
```